# Перегрузка оператора new[]

Tags: c++

Если я перегружаю оператор new[] в своем классе

```
void *MyString::operator new[](std::size_t size)
{
    //...
}
```

и далее пытаюсь при помощи new[] создать массив объектов

```
MyString *myS = new MyString[length];
```

Что конкретно передается в length?
При попытке передать в length количество элементов массива, в реализации оператора переменная  size увеличивается. В некоторых источниках говорится, что size это объем памяти, необходимый для массива с учетом размера класса, но при попытке использовать

```
length = size / sizeof(MyString);
```

все еще выдает некорректные значения

Полный код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyChar
{
public:
    MyChar(){};
    ~MyChar(){};

    void *operator new[](size_t);

private:
    char value = '0';
};

void *MyChar::operator new[](size_t size)
{
    cout << "Size in class: " << size << endl;
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    int len = 10;
    
    cout << len << endl;
    MyChar *c = new MyChar[len];
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/YdNnh9 — еще что-то надо пояснять?

Comment: *"При попытке передать в length количество элементов массива, в реализации оператора переменная size увеличивается."* - логично же, ведь для чем больше элементов в массиве, тем больше памяти для них нужно выделить.

Comment: В данном случае мне было достаточно убрать свою реализацию данного оператора, что бы моя программа работала корректно, но все же вопрос остается тем же. @harry-from-kiev мой код был написан ровно также, как предложенный вами, но, увы, результаты разные. При вводе длинны, к примеру, 10, size равнялся сначала 9, а потом и вовсе 18 (проблема была конкретно в моей перегрузке, хотя лишних вызовов там не было). Размер класса ровно один байт

Comment: Вот для 1 байта: https://ideone.com/FNGIUm Приведите код, который дает ваши результаты...

Comment: @harry-from-kiev я добавил полный код в самом вопросе, в данном случае он выдает 18

Comment: ¿Что по-вашему не так с этим результатом? ¿Какой результат вы ожидаете? Вроде все логично - 10 байт на сам массив из 10 элементов, еще 8 на служебный оверхед (размер и т.п.).

Comment: @user7860670 Вот эта информация мне и нужна была :D, только вот... в примере выше этой восьмерки не было, хотя вроде все тоже самое... И читая про перегрузку оператора new[] тоже ничего такого не было написано

Comment: А я никакого примера не приводил.

Comment: Я вас с другим пользователем спутал), уже исправил

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не могу сказать по поводу примера выше, так как у меня тот сайт не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При перегрузке `operator new []` функция будет получать на вход требуемый размер буфера, в байтах. Этот размер может быть больше, чем размер, непосредственно необходимый для хранения массива, так как в нем же может храниться служебная информация, например размер массива. Потребность в этой служебной информации может возникать например при создании массива объектов с нетривиальным деструктором - при вызове `delete []` компилятор должен будет сгенерировать код, который проходится по каждому элементу массива и вызывает деструктор, а размер массива в этот оператор не передается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstddef>

struct t_Trivial
{
    ~t_Trivial(void) = default;

    void * operator new [](::std::size_t const size)
    {
        ::std::cout << "sizeof(trivial) " << sizeof(t_Trivial)
            << " size: " << size << ::std::endl;
        return ::operator new [](size);
    }
};

struct t_NonTrivial
{
    ~t_NonTrivial(void){}

    void * operator new [](::std::size_t const size)
    {
        ::std::cout << "sizeof(nontrivial) " << sizeof(t_NonTrivial)
            << " size: " << size << ::std::endl;
        return ::operator new [](size);
    }
};

int main()
{
    ::std::size_t const len{10};
    auto p_trivial{new t_Trivial [len]};
    auto p_non_trivial{new t_NonTrivial [len]};
    return 0;
}
```

> sizeof(trivial) 1 size: 10
> sizeof(nontrivial) 1 size: 18

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwAbKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIGb%2BpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YnJtpj2JQxCBEzEBLk%2BfmbBdpgO2U0tBGXRcQlJKQrNre35XbZTQxEjlWPJAJS2qF7EyOwc5v4RyN5YANQm/m5Ok8SYrBfYJhoAggdHJ5jnl5EA7g9Pr2S7y8ZwubmQk3QWCo/xeAJuXgcpwIAH0ACrEPAANzwYgBJgA7FY4RoAJwAP1RGOxuNoECxqDw6DWXwAIqdoUwvLQCBdia8SaSGUzTgAqU6oVIJJhEYinX7nACsVkVrIgIBAkI1mQAXpgUQRTmgGJNTrrMGt8WTCfynqS7dqCOgNWgvIawWDzmYzObUFQIARMTixCzzGYvm5Pb7/VSg7TLYK7UnLp6w2a8HqQF7wx7Lum9RHPY7nSBXLQ%2BVb7WTbgRtgxThrJdLZfLMD8lSq1ebLf5bdaCaz8QOKyTngikaiogJqcHy3CiZXKSipwwZ7T6YzmTbCYPR3bhegxRKpcQZSRW%2B2TMqr2ri9qM/rDcbTd3K9vE2S7ygtu6U3mw9GEAMLIcYhtmhZ5oBk7TqBtAJgKVaIbmbjgeaWZpsh%2BafJhX5liOCF2jWdYNiATani2CpXp2ECvr2b7DvOg50aOESGiwTARBA8HvghX7mgaRoCKa9AMDaXAaDu%2BF2lyRCnKkBqwTaCqxjSYgdiJN6ScxCEyagckosBDAKap5ZEspy4wSZ6mMJpw7aYRmC1sQ9YSfZDHPBwGy0Jwiq8H4HBaKQqCcJGljWGaWw7NhyQ8KQBCaJ5GwANYgIqGj6Jwkh%2BQlQWcLwCggOl8UBZ5pBwLASCYKovRuiQ5CUC0wAKMohh1EICCoD8/mxWgLCpHQMrZC1kS0O1nX%2BYFvX9fQiTAFwXBmKQU10AkADybpjV1OVVb0zzEE1eUhNVyBNPg/m8PwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6glaQuhcPohjGNY1j6HgsQFZAGySg0BUcAAtGDkIXKyphhZYXAEqcYMAOpiLQSPI1VgZMBjUroIYjjIPlkW7HokIRMNbUdVt3C8IGmB7LFPynqknA8F5PnZS9wUcNgx21XKqgAByBGDgSSKcwDIMgpzzQAdOGEChVYlikKcuCEOeBxcGsdMJWsyWpel3kcFlpATbwPP5YVcX6xzHBmFzgVW7bJUG6QWIJJkziSEAA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: зы Из такой перегрузки оператора нельзя возвращать `nullptr`, только валидный указатель, либо исключение при ошибке.